# Reading java class file(?) from url as plain text in ubuntu terminal

Tags: java, json, linux, ubuntu, screen-scraping

I am not sure if the title makes sense.
I am not very experienced in this kind of stuff.

This is the situation:

I am running a linux server with Ubuntu 20.04

I run a program through .sh scripts for scraping web pages from different URLs.

One url gives back a file which starts like this:

```
{"javaClass":"java.util.ArrayList","list":[
```

I am not sure if this is a Java Class file or a JSON file, becasue the url has no extension.

I can call this url in my browser and it will be displayed as text. (That's why I can see the above code.)

If I call it with curl in Ubuntu terminal, it does nothing.

How can I display and read this as plain text in Ubuntu Terminal for processing the data, like I do in my Chrome browser?

EDIT: The url in question is this: https://www.yes.co.il/o/yes/servletlinearsched/getscheduale?startdate=20211025&p_auth=w3wmBNc5

EDIT2: The token at the end is every time different. I read the token right, so that is not the issue.

I found out that the site makes requests for x-dtpc cookies.
I found this about x-dtpc cookies:

> this header is set by the JavaScript agent on XHRs and is used for correlating XHR requests to user actions

When I open the page and get the url from the developer console, I can open the url in a new tab. If I get the url through my script, I can not open the url in the browser.

I load standard cookies, but apparently that's not enough.

Comment: It is JSON, without a doubt.  It has at least one attribute with Java-specific meaning, but it is still a JSON object.  Anything that can process JSON should be able to process it.  Java .class files have a binary format that is not human readable.

Comment: You should be able to get the output using curl. Probably you need to specify application/json as desired output for the request. Otherwise add your curl command to the question for additional help.

Comment: @dpr I edited the request. I added the url in question.

Comment: What is in the Content-Type header when you have a successful call?

Comment: @stdunbar when I call the original site https://www.yes.co.il/content/tvguide, the content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

When I call the site with the json data, which is part of the main site, it has no content type, just an x-content-type-options: nosniff in the response header :-(

Comment: Is there a specific order of actions on the yes.co.il page that will lead to a valid download url? My Hebrew is not the best I think…

Comment: @dpr There is no specific order of actions. I simply call the site in Chrome. In the developer console you find the url  https://www.yes.co.il/o/yes/servletlinearsched/getscheduale with method POST. I simply put together the url from the base url and the post data. When I open it in the Chrome browser in a new tab while the original site is still open, I get the data in the browser.
If I want to call the put together url in a new browser window, it doesn't work anymore.

I already tried to load all the headers when calling the put together url and also downloading the cookie. continued

Comment: Nothing works.
However the cookie is different when I download it (less data), as the one that is downloaded in the browser (more data), so maybe it depends on the cookie, but I don't know how to get the cookie with the more data.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If yes would you mind to accept the answer?

Answer (score 2):

In the chrome dev tools you can right click on the specific request and copy the corresponding cURL. As I opened the page the following command was created:

```
curl 'https://www.yes.co.il/o/yes/servletlinearsched/getscheduale' \
  -H 'authority: www.yes.co.il' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"' \
  -H 'dnt: 1' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'x-dtpc: 1$418482539_291h9vJHPPKPVFOURUFMBUBCNHWPOEEHUEJATA-0e5' \
  -H 'accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01' \
  -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'origin: https://www.yes.co.il' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'referer: https://www.yes.co.il/content/tvguide' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8' \
  -H 'cookie: TS01be6705=01ef05715da91cbd2bd3d3708b62fc37483302654019cffd2d42c61fe786389bea0697bdddc6cfaa989d8e83d7ecaf362d163c3ba4d4cc2cb2171d826bc2189e24b33b372f; COOKIE_SUPPORT=true; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=iw_IL; rxVisitor=1635415629464DQEQ6RQ2S8SQQ1QCFS5J66I2US8LK1NG; _gcl_au=1.1.2116753794.1635415632; _gid=GA1.3.1516801157.1635415633; dtSa=-; _ga=GA1.3.1003301072.1635415633; LFR_SESSION_STATE_33706=1635417685179; JSESSIONID=B399B241579DB87AF9FEC02AD72D62CF.worker_ip-10-0-3-108.eu-west-1.compute.internal; dtCookie==3=srv=1=sn=BF10E6A2EFEE80BE2CAD31F302CAF608=perc=100000=ol=0=mul=1=app:e6d1c681b48e20c9=0; _ga_H6Z9EGVSQX=GS1.1.1635418482.2.0.1635418482.0; dtLatC=14; AWSALB=1Ky1qIweYH/VBDu2pUv/DACVcWq5dmx3PPhlghfLR0g4oNTdMV78d7G08LreVX0l2Lvm0wdW5oRh+3j+THyZKDQmVldChB6XScu8+BVkqbSymgNrvMm4dOdT6TNL; AWSALBCORS=1Ky1qIweYH/VBDu2pUv/DACVcWq5dmx3PPhlghfLR0g4oNTdMV78d7G08LreVX0l2Lvm0wdW5oRh+3j+THyZKDQmVldChB6XScu8+BVkqbSymgNrvMm4dOdT6TNL; TS01542e32=01ef05715d1819fe7529d33b6e77731cfbb0015d8964ad5bb6c2e651cbb0a0a4b1882c8fa451246095770e14517339cd0a68861c971608fb5c8f0731d6c968c519acbcd35ea68d53e6fc4ceb067d99238c1dfce91a494ac4abf599a7d66a54b92c363e5c1b004d2d59e86f6198819dd2f1b43c0191; dtPC=1$418482539_291h9vJHPPKPVFOURUFMBUBCNHWPOEEHUEJATA-0e5; rxvt=1635420284821|1635415629471' \
  --data-raw 'startdate=20211028&p_auth=c43Cdm7P' \
  --compressed
```

Most of the headers don't seem to be too relevant thus I was able to boil it down to

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://www.yes.co.il/o/yes/servletlinearsched/getscheduale' \
--header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'cookie:  JSESSIONID=B399B241579DB87AF9FEC02AD72D62CF.worker_ip-10-0-3-108.eu-west-1.compute.internal;' \
--data-urlencode 'startdate=20211028' \
--data-urlencode 'p_auth=c43Cdm7P'
```

There is however the `JSESSIONID` cookie this is set by the initial request to the page and potentially updated by further requests. That's why a request only works for a limited time without using a new session id. Your **scraper** will have to extract a session id from previous requests and use this one.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this and didn't help. I am loading cookies, the start date and the p_auth anyway, but I tried to load the JSESSIONID again and it didn't make any difference. However I just recognized that when I call the yes.co.il site, in the remote address I get a different IP than when I call the getschedulae url directly. Both are Amazon IPs, but it seems that I have a routing problem here. The question is, how can I tell my script to call the url at a certain IP.

Answer (score 1):

That is the output of a tool that 'serializes' (turns objects that live in memory into a byte-based representation that can be transported over a network or stored on disk), specifically, that serialized an ArrayList into a JSON format.

The best way to read this with java code is to figure out which tool was used, and use the same tool. It's not baked into java itself; it's some third party library such as Jackson.

All such tools I know of have a 'hardcoded' special exception for anything that extends `java.util.List` (such as ArrayList), to just treat it as a plain JSON list. So, I'm a bit mystified as to what tool has been used here.

But, either [A] find the tool, or [B] reverse engineer the output.

NB: Ordinarily such serializer tools will represent in the JSON both the class name as well as each field. However, the relevant field in ArrayList is called `elementData` and not `list`. That is another further raised eyebrow: This is just bizarre.

Comment: The OP was asking how the read the data as plain text in the Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I understood about half of it :-)
@dpr is right. I simply want to be able to read this in terminal. If I can do that, I can also process it through my scripts.